# Xen and Linux cannot create directory while root

Tags: linux, xen

This question is pretty straightforward.  I've googled around and not seen any help.

```
root@sdna-23 :) #pwd
/sys/hypervisor
root@sdna-23 :) #whoami
root
root@sdna-23 :) #mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory `test': No such file or directory  
root@sdna-23 :( #
```

.....Why? I want to copy files into this directory....that won't work either....

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-filesystems such as sysfs and procfs are managed by the kernel, and as such cannot be modified by userspace (with a few exceptions).

Why do you want to modify the `/sys/hypervisor` directory?

Comment: So...long story short.  I made a backup copy of this machine using remastersys.  When I loaded the backup xen wouldn't work.  Along the process of understanding why it doesn't work I noticed `/sys/hypervisor` is empty...so I figured I could try to copy the originals contents in to it. Im new to xen....

Comment: Any advice on how to backup a xen system would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the directory you are in right now (/sys/hypervisor) has not been deleted by someone or something.

Comment: I'm the only one on the system. It exists.  There are real files in it.

Comment: Ah, yes. Ephemients answer has a more correct point anyway ;D